# PyQt5: Validate LineEdit through QPushButton using signals and slots

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt4, pyqt5

Having trouble connecting a QPushButton to a QMessageBox in PyQt5 as there seems to be little documentation in comparison with PyQt4. As it stands the QmessageBox is executing before the main layout I believe this to be an issue somewhere with `.self` and `.exec_()`?

The second, and main issue however is concerning connecting the two widgets. I am looking to implement some form of validity check; i.e when both `QLineEdit` fields contain text then on the click of 'Submit' the form should clear the fields, however if either of the fields are left blank when the 'submit' is clicked, Id like the `QMessageBox` to be opened. I'm unsure how to implement this as I don't know how to connect both the textField AND the PushButton together.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,QSpinBox, 
QDoubleSpinBox, QComboBox, QRadioButton, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication, QMessageBox

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
import csv

class Buttons (QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Widgets()
        self.arrange()
        self.close()
        self.messageBox()
        self.setWindowTitle ("test")



    def Widgets(self):

        self.nameLabel = QLabel("Name: ")
        self.nameLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.surnameLabel = QLabel("Surname: ")
        self.surnameLineEdit = QLineEdit()


        self.button1 = QPushButton("submit")
        self.button2 = QPushButton("cancel")
        self.button1.setMaximumSize(150,20)
        self.button2.setMaximumSize(150,20)



    def arrange (self):

        nameField = QVBoxLayout()
        nameField.addWidget(self.nameLabel)
        nameField.addWidget(self.nameLineEdit)
        nameField.addWidget(self.surnameLabel)
        nameField.addWidget(self.surnameLineEdit)

        #QHBoxLayout for Buttons:
        buttonsLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.button1.setSizePolicy(10,10)
        self.button2.setSizePolicy(10,10)



        #Creating mainLayout:
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(nameField)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def close(self):

        #close window
        self.button2.clicked.connect(app.quit)

    def clear(self):    
        pass
        #Clear textFields when button is clicked:   




    @pyqtSlot()
    def messageBox(self):
        self.message = QMessageBox()
        self.message.setText ("submit ERROR")
        self.message.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.messageBox)

        self.message.exec_()
```

I have tried a few different techniques none of which have worked successfully

```
        self.connect(self.Button1, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.clicked)
        def clicked(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "message!"(self.messageBox()))





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication (sys.argv)
    window = Buttons()
    window.show()
    sys.exit (app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read over your program and follow the path of execution. Start with `window = Buttons()` which means the `Buttons.__init__` method runs. Within this you run `Buttons.messageBox` which connects the `messageBox` slot to the `clicked` signal of `button1`. It then opens the message box (`self.message.exec_()`). Your `__init__` method eventually finishes and then `app.exec_()` is called which actually shows the main GUI and starts the Qt event loop which processes things like button clicks and redraw events.

At this point, your program has already been told to show the message box and is configured to run `Buttons.messageBox` when you click the button. When you click the button, it shows the message box, and makes an additional connection for the button. Next time you click the button you will get 2 message boxes showing!

The solution is to separate out the signal connection from the `messageBox` slot. Rather than calling `self.messageBox()` in your `__init__` method, make the signal connection for `button1` there.

```
class Buttons (QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Widgets()
        self.arrange()
        self.close()        
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.messageBox)
        self.setWindowTitle ("test")

    @pyqtSlot()
    def messageBox(self):
        self.message = QMessageBox()
        self.message.setText ("submit ERROR")
        self.message.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)

        self.message.exec_()
```